# Reverting a user's answer deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I have had a user present a reasonably solid, although incomplete (and thus technically incorrect) answer to one of my questions. I commented on this answer (call it answer A), pointing out where it fell short.

A second user subsequently posted an expansion on the original answer which dealt with the limitations of the original answer (call this answer B). As a result I accepted the answer B, however I also commented again on the answer A, asking if it is ok to edit it and fill in the missing gap based on answer B. Perhaps as retribution for not having accepted the original answer (and definitely without any explanation), the first user deleted answer A.

The whole question is now in an awkward situation where it has an accepted answer that is referring to a non-existent answer.

[The question I am referring to.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662688/conditional-probability-combining-discrete-and-continuous-variables) Note how @Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen (answer B) is quoting @Did's (answer A).

Is there a way to un-delete answers or will this question have to remain incomplete indefinitely?

Comment: A moderator, three users with more than 10k reputation, or the user who posted the answer can undelete. As for myself I wouldn't vote to undelete it if Did wants the answer to remain deleted (especially considering the comments on the answer). My best advice would be to edit the existing accepted answer to add the missing details, I guess.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi minor detail, for answers I think it'd be 20k. I agree on the rest.